# MacBook Pro won't sleep when closing lid

Tags: macbook

My one month old MacBook Pro suddenly does not sleep anymore when I close the lid. There might be a relation to the Caffeine program that I installed recently. Caffeine prevents a Mac from going into sleep. But I have the problem when Caffeine is not even running.

What reasons could there be for this problem happening? I'm hoping its a software problem instead of some hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting PRAM and NVRAM (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) is apparently a method. But simply restarting the machine seems to be the first method to try and may actually solve the problem. :)

Comment: Upvoting just so it doesn't stay in "Unanswered" forever.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that when I installed Entourage on My mac.

It disappeared when I uninstalled Entourage.
Not sure if that help but I tried :)